# Solr returning empty results with accurate pager

Tags: 7, search

I'm running Drupal 7 with the Apache Solr module version 7.x-1.6, it's configured and seems to be connecting to the Solr server properly.  However when I try to use a search box, there are no results for my queries.  There is no error message or no results found message.  However the pager for the results does render, and it seems to be accurate since the number of pages changes as I search for different terms.  I looked at the page results template file and saw that the variable $search_results is an empty string.

I'm a bit of a newcomer to Solr, any suggestions as to what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to clear the index and re-index the site?

Comment: I tried that, but when rebuilding the index I get the error: 
Error message
An error occurred while processing apachesolr_index_batch_index_entities with arguments: apachesolr_index_batch_index_entities

Comment: Look at comment #12 here https://drupal.org/node/1700280
Maybe this can help you